# Git problems with "authored and committed" issues when rebasing/merging

Tags: git

I am not too familiar with git, so I am having some trouble working with it.

At the moment, my branch is 26 commits behind and also 29 commits ahead. This was caused by the following:

I made a branch from the master about 3 days ago, lets call it "bugFix" and made 2 commits fixing a bug. I pushed these changes to bugFix on the remote. Then, today, I made one more commit to bugFix. In this time, 26 commits were made on the master, so I pulled the remote master to my master, rebased bugFix to the master locally, and then tried to push it. It gave me an error that I needed to pull the remote before pushing, so I did that using "git pull -rebase".

However, now I have a really messy commit history because of that, it shows all 26 commits that were made were "authored by X and committed by me", while on the master all 26 commits are simply committed by X. Thus my branch is now 26 commits behind and 29 commits ahead. How can I prevent this from happening in the future?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I prevent this from happening in the future?

The problem occurs when you do `git pull --rebase` because the remote bugfix branch doesn't contain the 26 commits from master. When you did the rebase, git created 26 new commits that are copies of the changes in the 26 commits on master, but with a different history (and probably committer).

To fix this, you can reset your local bugfix branch back to the 3 commits that were rebased onto master. Then you can do `git push -f` to forcefully overwrite the remote version of the bugfix branch.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I did pull remote master before that.

Comment: @AndrewZaw After the rebase, you should do `git push -f` to forcefully overwrite the remote bugfix branch. Be sure to only do this if you are the only person working on the branch, though.